# trouble reading nested Object value with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am having some trouble with knockout reading value.
i have objects that look  like this:

[image]

```
<div data-bind="text: domains.length"></div> //output = 0
```

and

[image]

```
<div data-bind="text: domains[0].domain"></div> //output = Cannot read property 'domain' of undefined
```

what is going wrong there?.

By the way i am using `return viewmodel;` it s on a `hottowel/durandal` project with `mapping.fromJS`

Comment: How did you create the view model that was passed to `ko.applyBindings()`?

Comment: no with `return viewmodel;` it s on a `hottowel/durandal` project and i am using `mapping.fromJS`

Comment: If `domains.length` really is 0, the object you're inspecting and the one that is actually bound at that point are different.

Comment: Assuming `domains` is an `observableArray` you simply need to invoke it before accessing it's value: `text: domains().length` and `text: domains()[0].domain`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting error in time when you have no items in domains array.

M.b. it is make sens **to add knockout "if" statement** before text binding?

```
<div data-bind="if:domains().length > 0">
  <div data-bind="text: domains()[0].domain"></div>
</div>
```

or Virtual if statement:

```
<!-- ko if: domains.length > 0-->
   <div data-bind="text: domains()[0].domain"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```